# How to run rspec (or any other) tests in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: testing, kubernetes, rspec, jasmine, tilt

I changed my dev workflow to mainly develop in Kubernetes (with Tilt.dev). All dependencies are running, file changes are syncing etc..

Now I stuck in the rSpec test process:

- How do you run your tests in a Kubernetes cluster?
- How do you deal the dev dependencies, the production image does not contain the required dependencies?
- How do you kickoff the tests `rspec spec`?

Are you installing gems subsequently?
Are you creating a extra "test" image for that case?

I didn't found any bootstrap code. I am totally lost.